# Neither nor statement in python

Tags: python

I want to combine the following two lists except the combination 1a.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b=['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e','f','g']
c=[]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i is not 1 and j is not'a':
            c.append(str(i) + j)

print c
```

This excludes every combination with 1 and 'a'. How can I only exclude 1a

Comment: Never compare integers or floats with `is`. Use `==` and `!=`.

Comment: boolean algebra 101, De Morgan's law.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite of "i is 1 and j is 'a'" is not "i is not 1 and j is not 'a'". You also need to flip the binary operator. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more information.

Also, you should use the equality operator `==` instead of `is` when you're comparing values.

```
if i is not 1 and j is not'a':
```

Change this to:

```
if i != 1 or j != 'a':
```

Answer (score 3):

what you want is

```
if not (i == 1 and j == 'a')
```

or, alternatively

```
 if i != 1 or j != 'a'
```